# can we check push notification in simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, apple-push-notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I test Apple Push Notification Service without an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080556/how-can-i-test-apple-push-notification-service-without-an-iphone)

I want to know that can we receive push notification on iPhone Simulator or not. Also, I want something like this tell me if it is possible that, the app opens unregistered for push notification and when app terminates register for push notification.

Comment: Local Push Notifications are working just fine in Xcode 7+ Simulators.

Comment: Local push notification working over XCode 10.1 simulator (Y)

Comment: https://medium.com/@lokesh.vyas4/ios-push-notification-from-terminal-to-app-d01019934758

Comment: https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-send-push-notifications-to-the-ios-simulator-2988092ba931

Comment: It’s finally possible! https://stackoverflow.com/a/73829063/1351469

Answer (score 122, accepted):

The iPhone Simulator is unable to receive push notifications or successfully register for them.

See the following:
[How can I test Apple Push Notification Service without an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080556/how-can-i-test-apple-push-notification-service-without-an-iphone)

Comment: In the XCode11.4 beta, they added the feature which allows testing push notification on the simulator.

Comment: Xcode 11.4 beta released with simulator to support remote push notifications: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60205613/905517

Comment: As of Xcode 11.4, you can start sending pushnotifications to the simulator using the command, xcrun simctl push <device-identifier> <your-bundle-id> <your_apns_file.apns>

more information here: https://ohmyswift.com/blog/2020/02/13/simulating-remote-push-notifications-in-a-simulator/

Comment: This is tutorial link for support Push notification in Simulator. https://medium.com/swlh/simulating-push-notifications-in-ios-simulator-9e5198bed4a4

Comment: FYI: Apple didn't added push notifications to simulator in Xcode 11.4, they added support for simulating push notifications. So this means that you cannot receive any push notifications, you can just simulate them.

Comment: Since Xcode 12 it's possible to registrer to push and receive via the APNS payload.

You can send a push like this :
xcrun simctl push booted YOUR_BUNDLE payload.json

booted = the current simulator
payload.json is the APNS file on your Mac :

{
    "Simulator Target Bundle": "xxx.xxx.xx ",
    "aps":{
                    "alert":{
                        "title":"XXX",
                        "body":"YYY YYYY"
                    },
                    "data":{
                   // stuff
                    },
                    "mutable-content":1
                }
}

Comment: https://medium.com/@lokesh.vyas4/ios-push-notification-from-terminal-to-app-d01019934758

Comment: It’s finally possible! https://stackoverflow.com/a/73829063/1351469

Comment: What about background push notifications (or silent notifications)? Can that be simulated? Background fetch and Background processing cannot be tested in simulator though.