# Laravel FCM push notification not working for iOS, but working with Android - brozot/laravel-fcm

Tags: php, laravel, firebase-cloud-messaging

Laravel FCM push notification not working for iOS, but working with Android - brozot/laravel-fcm

```
config(['fcm.http.server_key' => $shop_data->fcm_server_key]);
                config(['fcm.http.sender_id' => $shop_data->fcm_sender_id]);

                $optionBuilder = new OptionsBuilder();
                $optionBuilder->setTimeToLive(60 * 20);

                $notificationBuilder = new PayloadNotificationBuilder($message);
                $notificationBuilder->setBody($message_image)
                    ->setSound('default');

                $dataBuilder = new PayloadDataBuilder();
                $dataBuilder->addData(['message' => trim($message), 'image' => trim($message_image)]);

                $option = $optionBuilder->build();
                $notification = $notificationBuilder->build();
                $data = $dataBuilder->build();

                $device_groups = DeviceGroup::where('shop_id', $shop_id)->get();
                foreach ($device_groups as $device_group) {
                    $groupResponse = FCM::sendToGroup($device_group->group_key, $option, null, $data);
                    $groupResponse->numberSuccess();
                    $groupResponse->numberFailure();
                    $groupResponse->tokensFailed();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for FCM for iOS. Its a good idea to put it in a Trait. Don't forget to include:

```
use LaravelFCM\Message\OptionsBuilder;
use LaravelFCM\Message\PayloadDataBuilder;
use LaravelFCM\Message\PayloadNotificationBuilder;
use FCM;
use Log;

  try {

            $sound = 'default';
            if (!empty($notification_sound)) {
                $sound = $notification_sound;
            }

            $ttl = 15;
            if (!empty($time_to_live)) {
                $ttl = $time_to_live;
            }


            $notificationBuilder = new PayloadNotificationBuilder();
            $notificationBuilder
                ->setTitle($push_tittle)
                ->setSound($sound)
                //                ->setIcon(FAV_ICON)
                //                ->setColor('#fc547f')
            ;

            $dataBuilder = new PayloadDataBuilder();
            $dataBuilder->addData([
                'custom' => $data //sending custom data
            ]);

            $optionBuilder = new OptionsBuilder();
            $optionBuilder->setTimeToLive($ttl);


            $notification = $notificationBuilder->build();
            $data = $dataBuilder->build();
            $option = $optionBuilder->build();



            //            Log::debug( ' Push $notification' .  json_encode($notification->toArray()));
            //            Log::debug( ' Push $option' .  json_encode($option->toArray()));
            //            Log::debug( '  Push $data' .  json_encode($data->toArray()));

            $downstreamResponse = FCM::sendTo($device_id, $option, $notification, $data);





            return $downstreamResponse;

        } catch (\Exception $e) {

            Log::debug(' Error message Push  ' . $e->getMessage());
            Log::debug(' Error message Push  ' . $e->getFile());
            Log::debug(' Error message Push  ' . $e->getLine());
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying using ios simulator it will not work. You need to use some tools like testflight or real device to test.

[can we check push notification in simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811900/can-we-check-push-notification-in-simulator)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `setContentAvailable(true)` to send silent notification to iOS:

```
$optionBuilder = new OptionsBuilder(); 
$optionBuilder->setContentAvailable(true); 
$optionBuilder->setPriority(OptionsPriorities::normal); 
$dataBuilder = new PayloadDataBuilder(); 
$dataBuilder->addData($data); 
$option = $optionBuilder->build(); 
$data = $dataBuilder->build();

$downstreamResponse = FCM::sendTo($token, $option, null, $data);
```