# Test Rich Notifications in Simulator

Tags: xcode, apple-push-notifications, ios-simulator, xcode11.4, unnotificationserviceextension

I am able to test the normal notifications in Simulator, but when I tried to test rich notifications nothing happens, event title is not getting updated.

Could you please assist me, how to proceed. Do I need to change any simulator settings?
I am using Xcode 11.4

Sample Payload :

```
{
    "aps": {
        "mutable-content": 1,
        "alert": {
            "body": "Push notification body",
            "title": "Push notification title"
        }
    },
    "media-url": "https://i.imgur.com/t4WGJQx.jpg"
}
```

NotificationService Extension Method:

```
- (void)didReceiveNotificationRequest:(UNNotificationRequest *)request withContentHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationContent * _Nonnull))contentHandler {
     self.contentHandler = contentHandler;
     self.bestAttemptContent = [request.content mutableCopy];
    
    self.bestAttemptContent.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ [modified]",
    self.bestAttemptContent.title];
}
```

Comment: Xcode 14 has a fix...

Answer (score 13):

## Possible Xcode 14 workaround

[Xcode 14 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-14-release-notes):

> Simulator now supports remote notifications in iOS 16 when running in
> macOS 13 on Mac computers with Apple silicon or T2 processors.
> Simulator supports the Apple Push Notification Service Sandbox
> environment. Your server can send a remote notification to your app
> running in that simulator by connecting to the APNS Sandbox
> (api.sandbox.push.apple.com). Each simulator generates registration
> tokens unique to the combination of that simulator and the Mac
> hardware it’s running on. See User Notifications for more information.
>
> Remote Notifications support **more features** (like Notification Service
> Extensions) than locally simulated notifications using `.apns` payload
> files or the `simctl` push command.

Based on docs starting from Xcode14:

- *remote* notification sent to the simulator: will be passed to the Notification Service Extension.
- *locally simulated* notification sent to the simulator: will NOT passed to the Notification Service Extension.

### OLD Answer

See [older revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/60892213/5) of this answer for Older Xcode versions up to Xcode 13.

Comment: FYI This is still not fixed in 12.5 Beta.

Comment: Another FYI, still does not seem to resolved in 13.4.1

Comment: After investing hours on this, found out Service extensions are not supported on simulator. It worked while testing on real device.

Comment: As of Xcode version Version 14.3.1, you still cannot test Notification Service Extensions in the simulator.  It will not honor 'mutable-content'.  You can, however, test Notification Content Extensions.  The simulator does honor 'category'.  Yes, it is frustrating.

Comment: @smakus I _think_ it actually depends. see my updated answer

Comment: I just tested this, using Xcode 15. I sent a mutable notification from the "Push Notifications" part of this [dashboard](https://icloud.developer.apple.com/dashboard). The aps dictionary should contain a "mutable-content" key, with the integer value of 1. I could edit the received contents in the SceneDelegate, and the edits showed in the simulator.

Comment: @Jonny Thanks for mentioning it here. I updated my answer