# Testing ios push notifications with Xcode 11.4 - link in apns is not working

Tags: ios, push-notification, xcode11.4

I'm trying to test push notifications in ios simulator with a new Xcode 11.4 feature.

My app has both NotificationService and NotificationContent extensions to change the message before showing it to the user.

To send a notification to the simulator I'm using terminal command:

```
xcrun simctl push <simulator_id> <app_bundle_id> push.apns
```

My push.apns is like this:

```
{
"Simulator Target Bundle": "app_bundle_id",
   "aps":{  
      "category": "NewOrder",
      "alert": {
           "loc-key": "NOTIFICATION_KEY",
           "loc-args": ["3"]
       },
      "badge": 1,
      "sound": "default",
      "types": ["order.created"],
      "storeId": "4616",
      "mutable-content": 1,
      "link": "my-app://orders/3",
      "thread-id": "OrderThreadId"
   }
}
```

I see the notification on the screen, but it seems that the "link" attribute is not working. When I tab on a push, I expect to see, in this case, the screen of the third order, but I see the main screen of the app.

I'll be appreciated for any help with this. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Test Rich Notifications in Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60888395/test-rich-notifications-in-simulator)