# ios simulator - where is settings>notifications>appname?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I built a VOIP app for iphone where if you receive a call, you will hear a telephone ring tone.  Some users have complained that they don't hear any ringtone.  I discovered later that on the physical device, you can go to Settings>Notifications>TheAppName, and adjust your notification settings.  One of htese settings is to disable sounds or allow sound, which corresponds to whether you get the ringtone or not when receiving a call.  However, some users still don't seem to hear the ringtone at all despite having the most permissive sound settings.

I wanted to reproduce their issues in the iOS simulator.  But I can't seem to find the Settings>NOtifications in the simulator.  How do I locate this?

Comment: In short, you can't do this on the simulator - see the existing [How can I test Apple Push Notification Service without an iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080556/how-can-i-test-apple-push-notification-service-without-an-iphone) question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot test push notification services on the simulator. You have to use a device to test it.

Comment: In order to troubleshoot our bug "some users complain they don't hear a ring tone when receiving a voip call in our app", can we just get a used iphone 4 and install various IOS versions to it, and expect it to provide all the different environments we need to test for (ie. every combination of iphone 3gs and above with ios 5.0 and above)

Comment: First of all, you cannot make an iphone 4 emulate the 3gs. Also, although it is not impossible, it is very difficult to install a lower ios version than the newest one, as apple does not want users installing older versions. My guess is that if it works on the newest version, it should work for all, although if that is not the case it would be difficult to test it on all versions. If it is just some users that do not get sounds, they may have accidentally disabled them in the notification settings.