# ios 8 Simulator , is it possible to send push notification to the simulator

Tags: ios, push-notification, ios8, ios8.1

When i run the app in ios 8 Simultor, it is showing alert do you want to allow push notifications and in settings i am able to see push notification enabled. So here can we send push notifications to the simulator? is it possible?

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25943924/1753005

Comment: As of Xcode 11.4, you can simulate remote notifications using a sample push notificaiton payload in simulators. Check this link for more detailed explanation: https://ohmyswift.com/blog/2020/02/13/simulating-remote-push-notifications-in-a-simulator/

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can check push notification on simulator but you have to use a library in your app Named [SimulatorRemoteNotifications](https://github.com/acoomans/SimulatorRemoteNotifications). By which by using just 4-5 steps you can test push notification on Simulator.

They Also Provide PODs too

```
pod 'SimulatorRemoteNotifications', '~> 0.0.3'
```