# In IOS Simulator i cant able to view the notification is there any setting on simulator to get the notification in notification bar

Tags: ios, selenium, ios-simulator, ios-web-app, ios-webkit-debug-proxy

In ios simulator, I cant able to view the notification is there any setting on a simulator to get the notification in notification bar.i am using the hybrid app.

Comment: If you used push notification than you'll need some hardware to test...for more you can also refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1082908/10584330

Comment: For push notification you must need Apple device to see it, not possible on simulator. But local notification can be seen on iOS simulators.

Comment: Thanks, Mahendra i am trying to know the setting only for local notification I am not getting a local notification in the simulator