# how to test push notification on iOS without real device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone

I want to test push notification on iOS.
I have no real device.
How can I test this with iOS simulator?
If you have any solution, please help me.

Comment: You can't do it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I test Apple Push Notification Service without an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080556/how-can-i-test-apple-push-notification-service-without-an-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

> You must have to use a real device to test if push notifications are
>   working or not since push notifications aren’t supported in Xcode’s
>   iOS Simulator.

***Xcode 11.4 beta is out and the best part about this release for me is that we can finally test push notifications in the iOS Simulator!***

> “Simulator supports simulating remote push notifications, including
>   background content fetch notifications. In Simulator, drag and drop an
>   APNs file onto the target simulator. The file must be a JSON file with
>   a valid Apple Push Notification Service payload, including the “aps”
>   key. It must also contain a top-level “Simulator Target Bundle” with a
>   string value matching the target application‘s bundle identifier.
>   simctl also supports sending simulated push notifications. If the file
>   contains “Simulator Target Bundle” the bundle identifier is not
>   required, otherwise you must provide it as an argument (8164566):

```
 $ xcrun simctl push <device> com.example.my-app ExamplePush.apns"
```

Read here: https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-send-push-notifications-to-the-ios-simulator-2988092ba931