# Debugging push notifications on iOS emulator

Tags: xamarin.forms, push-notification, xamarin.ios

I have a xamarin.forms app. I would like to debug push notifications for iOS on an emulator. I have read that in newer versions on xCode I should be able to do that, but for some reason it doesn't work for me. Though the push notifications do come to my app on a real iPhone, it doesn't happen on the emulator. What can I be missing? Again, it does work on a real iPhone. And I just updated the xCode.

Comment: Hi, do you use the `xcrun simctl push` to test remote push notification in simulator?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I use a testing tool at Azure Devops (Notification Hub).

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure whether Azure Devops supports. But you could check whether can get the `PushDeviceToken` In `AppDelegate.cs` first. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-ios-push-notification-apns-get-started

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Sorry, it is not clear to me what I should do, how I can check that and why.

Comment: Hi, from the shared document, Step 10 in **[Connect your app to the notification hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-ios-push-notification-apns-get-started#connect-your-app-to-the-notification-hub)** section, that will return device token. Have a check whether it works in your project.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT RegisteredForRemoteNotifications() is never reached, the breakpoint in it is not hit.

Comment: Okey, therefore the simulator device didn't register to the apple, maybe Azure Devops 
not supports now. I suggest use [xcrun simctl push](https://www.iosapptemplates.com/blog/swift-programming/push-notifications-simulator-ios) to test whehter it works.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT That is swift... and I work with c# and Xamarin.Forms...

Comment: Hi, I know that's swift. But there is a way to use `xcrun simctl push` to **Trigger Push Notifications**.  Because your deice not receiving a device token, that may be the device not be registered to **Apple Push Server**. Therefore, you'd better send the identifier of device or simulator manually.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT My problem is not to sent notifications, but to receive them.

Comment: Yes, I mean that the problem may be sending method. The general way to send notification, the simulator can not be registed to server. Therefore, we need to send the identifier of device or simulator manually.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I see, thanks. If you want to make it an answer, I will mark it.

Comment: Okey, I have updated the answer with more detailed information. And there is an another discussion that will be helpful. You could have a look when you have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of **Xcode 11.4**, it is now possible to simulate push notifications by **dragging and dropping** an `.apns` file onto the iOS simulator. The [Xcode 11.4 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_4_beta_release_notes/) have the following to say about the new feature:

> Simulator supports simulating remote push notifications, including
> background content fetch notifications. In Simulator, **drag and drop an
> APNs file onto the target simulator**. The file must be a JSON file with
> a valid Apple Push Notification Service payload, including the **“aps”
> key**. It must also contain a top-level **“Simulator Target Bundle”** with a
> string value matching the target application‘s bundle identifier.
>
> `simctl` also supports sending simulated push notifications. If the file
> contains “Simulator Target Bundle” the bundle identifier is not
> required, otherwise you must provide it as an argument (8164566):
>
> `xcrun simctl push <device> com.example.my-app ExamplePush.apns`

**Therefore**, I guess the general method to push notification can not register the device for apple push server. You'd better send the identifier of device or simulator by using **xcrun simctl push** manually.

Command code:

```
xcrun simctl push <the identifier of device or simulator> <bundle identifier> <path to apns file>
```

More info can refer to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080556/how-can-i-test-apple-push-notification-service-without-an-iphone/60085404#60085404).