# Can you receive FCM push notification from iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have recently started iOS development, and was trying to build a simple web based iOS application with push notification feature using Firebase.
I have tried about 3 tutorials about sending push notifications using FCM, including the one from official document, yet I could not receive any notifications from my iOS simulator.
At this point, I am wondering if iOS simulator from xcode is not capable of receiving cloud messaging.

ps. I haven't tested with physical iOS device. (I don't have one yet)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

After Xcode 11.4 [it is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1080556), but for firebase messaging it requires **`gcm.message_id`** value to be present. Otherwise it won't be handled by firebase SDK.

```json
{
  "Simulator Target Bundle": "<your bundle>",
  "aps": {
    "badge": 0,
    "alert": {
      "title": "Test Push",
      "body": "Success! Push notification in simulator! ",
      "sound": "default"
    }
  },

  "gcm.message_id": "123",
  "example-data-key": "example-data-value"
}
```

Comment: `gcm.message_id` was not mentioned in any other answer. Adding that successfully triggered the Firebase messaging related callbacks. Thanks!

Comment: Didn't work for me. It says "request contain invalid arguments" on iPhone 15 Pro Max Simulator with iOS 17

Comment: Knowing this doesn't work on a simulator would have saved me a massive amount of time. Was trying all different combinations of firebase cloud messaging configurations with no luck.

Answer (score 9):

Sorry to say, but you'll need to find some hardware to test this functionality.

Push notifications are not available in the simulator. They require a provisioning profile from iTunes Connect, and thus are required to be installed on a device. That also means you'll probably have to be accepted into the apple iPhone developer program and pay your $99.

[How can I test Apple Push Notification Service without an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080556/how-can-i-test-apple-push-notification-service-without-an-iphone)

Comment: Thank you anyway! At least I don't have to waste any more time on finding a way to make it working

Comment: It might be possible in Xcode 11.4 version please see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080556/how-can-i-test-apple-push-notification-service-without-an-iphone/60085404#60085404

Comment: I have seen that method from elsewhere, yet I cannot find a way to use it with Firebase. That feature seems like it is for testing how that app handles push notification. My current objective is to figure out if my firebase project can send message to my app, so it was no use for me ):

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Kindly use the below sample json

1. Create a New file with `APNSTest.apns`. (apns extention).
2. Save this file to your desktop.
3. Drag and drop to your simulator.

```
{
  "aps": {
    "alert": {
      "title": "New Offer Received",
      "body": "Open the app to grab new discount.",
      "sound": "default"
    }
  },
  "gcm.message_id": "123",
  "Simulator Target Bundle": "<BundleID (Bundle Identifier) com.abc.abc>",
  "type": "new_offer",
  "priority": "high",
  "content_available": true,
  "mutable_content": true,
  "offer_id": "123",
  "offer_description": " 50% off on selected product.",
}
```

###### Notes:

1. Extra parameters for custom data or custom logic (you don't need to add a "data" key, just add your key and value outside of the "aps" key, refer to the below JSON payload).
2. You must implement Firebase Push Notification Methods to handle your custom scenario.
3. must be added to the JSON payload with `gcm.message_id` to receive a firebase push notification in the iOS simulator.
4. Replace with your application Bundle Identifier, here is just for reference. `"Simulator Target Bundle": "com.abc.abc"`