# notifications are not supported in the simulator Error connecting using flutter framework

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

i run on android smoothly but on ios simulator get a description like this, i am using xcode version 13.1 and IOS Deployment Target 12.1. is there any solution

```
> Output debug console 
> Launching lib/main_development.dart on iPhone 11 Pro in debug mode...
> Running Xcode build...                                                
> └─Compiling, linking and signing...                         7.4s Xcode
> build done.                                                 29.9s remote
> notifications are not supported in the simulator Error connecting to
> the service protocol: failed to connect to
> http://127.0.0.1:62025/t8W6_uBW7Q0=/
```

Comment: Notification does not work in the simulator on iOS. Works only on real device.

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60085404/14207423