# dotnet 7 MAUI Push notifications for IOS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, maui

So, far the last few weeks I have tried to get push notifications working for IOS in MAUI Dotnet 7 on a Windows 11 machine using visual studio connected to a mac and Iphone.

Ive tried the following frameworks

- https://github.com/Gekidoku/BetterFireBaseNotificationsPlugin
- https://github.com/TobiasBuchholz/Plugin.Firebase
- https://github.com/shinyorg/shiny
- https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-DotNet-SDK

Tutorials

- https://cedricgabrang.medium.com/firebase-push-notifications-in-net-maui-ios-2f4388bf1ac
- https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/net-sdk-setup
- https://github.com/michalpr/Docs/blob/main/Firebase_MAUI_iOS_push_notification.md
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YNkdsJTyOJE&t=1262s

I've had everything from null references when initialising to running and getting a fcm key.
But at no point have I received a push notification.

Can anyone confirm if my setup works as I get the feeling I need to use a Mac with visual studio or visual studio code.

Also can someone clarify how I test its working. Im getting mixed messages. Basically can I test using the simulator, can I test in debug, do I need to use a physical device etc...

Thanks all

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080556/how-can-i-test-apple-push-notification-service-without-an-iphone

Comment: That post it 14 years old, how does it help me with MAUI?

Comment: You asked whether you can use the simulator to test push notifications, correct?

Comment: Yes but for a specific scenario. Dotnet maui on a Windows pc connected to a mac

Comment: The method of sending the push notification is irrelevant to if it’s possible to receive it in the simulator (unless the service has a fallback system that works in the sim)

Comment: What did you try, and where did it go wrong?